# Remove units from HKQuantity

Tags: ios, healthkit

Is there a way to get the value of an HKQuantity without the unit after it? Currently HKQuantities appear like:

- 69201.8 m
- 543 kcal
- 2 count/s
- etc.

Ideally I'd like to get the averageQuantity or sumQuantity as a string, so I can modify how it's displayed.

Comment: What code are you using to get the quantity? Because it seems as if 
quantityWithUnit:doubleValue: returns a unit and a value separately so you can use the value or unit as you see fit: https://developer.apple.com/Library/ios/documentation/HealthKit/Reference/HKQuantity_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/clm/HKQuantity/quantityWithUnit:doubleValue:

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The result of calling `[HKQuantity description]` is not intended to be used for display.  In general the `[NSObject description]` is primarily meant to be used as a debugging convenience.  You should use `[HKQuantity doubleValueForUnit:]` to get the value you want to display and then format the value using `NSNumberFormatter` and your own localized text for the unit.  HealthKit does not provide localization facilities for values or units.

Answer (score 1):

Apple's HealthKit docs state that you should use the MeasurementFormatter class:

> You can use [MeasurementFormatter](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/measurementformatter) to localize quantities such as length, mass, and energy. For other quantities, you need to perform the conversions and localize the data yourself.
>
> https://developer.apple.com/documentation/healthkit/samples/units_and_quantities/defining_and_converting_units_and_quantities

also mentioned on NSHipster:

> The only occasions in which you might still use EnergyFormatter, MassFormatter, or LengthFormatter are when working with the HealthKit framework; these formatters provide conversion and interoperability with HKUnit quantities.
>
> https://nshipster.com/formatter/#formatting-numbers-and-quantities